# Rails, I keep having 400 Bad Request on create and update and can't find out why

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying a form to create/update for **accommodation** model
I keep having 400 Bad Request on whichever one of them.
Checking my development.log, I can see

> ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is
>   empty: accommodation):
>   app/controllers/accommodations_controller.rb:75:in
>   `accommodation_params'
>   app/controllers/accommodations_controller.rb:12:in`create'

As you can see above my accommodation param keeps returning empty for line 75 in controller. I have indicated the lines in my controller below.
I can't find what is at fault here because I use the exact same code for my **area** model and it works perfectly. The models are also almost identical.

My update form:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <%=form_for @accommodation, url: accommodations_update_path, remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal",:multipart => true} do |f|%>

        <fieldset class="content-group">
          <legend class="text-bold">Images</legend>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 text-semibold">Current images: <span style="color:grey">Click to delete</span> </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <% @accommodation.accommodation_attachments.each do |a| %>
                <%unless a.image.blank?%>
                  <%= link_to delete_accommodation_attachment_path(a), :remote => true, :method => :delete,data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this image?"} do%>
                     <%= image_tag a.image_url(:thumb), class:"delete-image" %>                 
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 text-semibold">Add images:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">

            <%= f.fields_for :accommodation_attachments, @accommodation.accommodation_attachments.build do |aa| %>              
              <div class="field">
               <br>
               <%= aa.file_field :image, :multiple => true, name: "accommodation_attachments[image][]" %>
              </div>                          
            <% end %>
           </div>
         </div>

       </fieldset>                              
      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" >
        </div>

      </div>

      <% end %>
```

My accommodations_Controller

```
class AccommodationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_accommodations
    before_action :set_accommodation, only: [:edit, :delete, :update, :destroy]


    def new
        @accommodation = Accommodation.new
        @accommodation_attachment = @accommodation.accommodation_attachments.build
    end

    def create
        #LINE 12 IS THE NEXT ONE
          @accommodation = Accommodation.new(accommodation_params)

        if @accommodation.save
            params[:accommodation_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
                @accommodation_attachment = @accommodation.accommodation_attachments.create!(:image => a, :accommodation_id => @accommodation.id)
            end
            @status = 'success'
        else
            @status = 'error'
            @errormessages = @accommodation.errors.full_messages
        end
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end

    def edit        

    end

    def update

        if @accommodation.update(accommodation_params)
            params[:accommodation_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
                @accommodation_attachment = @accommodation.accommodation_attachments.create!(:image => a, :accommodation_id => @accommodation.id)
            end
            @status = 'success'
        else
            @status = 'error'
            @errormessages = @accommodation.errors.full_messages
        end
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end

    def delete_accommodation
        @accommodation = Accommodation.find(params[:id])
        @accommodation.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end

    def find_accommodation_by_id
        accommodation = Accommodation.find(params[:id])
        render json: accommodation
    end

    protected

    def news_list
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end



    private

    def accommodation_params
      #LINE 75 IS THE NEXT ONE
     params.require(:accommodation).permit(:id, accommodation_attachments_attributes: [:id, :accommodation_id, :image])
   end

    def set_accommodation
        @accommodation = Accommodation.find_by_id(params[:id])
        @languages = Language.all
        @accommodation_attachments = @accommodation.accommodation_attachments.all
        @accommodations = Accommodation.all
    end

    def set_accommodations
        @accommodations = Accommodation.all
        @article = Article.all
    end


end
```

My routes considering accommodations:

```
  get '/accommodations/new', to: 'accommodations#new', :as => 'accommodations_new'
  post '/accommodations/create', to: 'accommodations#create', :as => 'accommodations_create'
  get '/accommodations/:id/destroy', to: 'accommodations#destroy', :as => 'accommodations_destroy'
  delete 'delete_accommodation/:id', controller: 'accommodations', action: 'delete_accommodation'
  get '/accommodations/:id/edit', to: 'accommodations#edit', :as => 'accommodations_edit'
  patch '/accommodations/:id/update', to: 'accommodations#update', :as => 'accommodations_update'
```

Can you locate the problem here?
Any help appreciated.

In my development.log my POST

**Edit**

> Started POST "/accommodations/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-02
>   16:46:30 +0300 Processing by AccommodationsController#create as JS
>   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "remotipart_submitted"=>"true",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"iqwKYhO4LVGxIZuP9GHouEKCIbaC0AIB8Yb1EZsjfyTRiaYBH23xAeg65mqSrNUXfuz7t51Px8TI/jj+ZGVinQ==",
>   "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript,
>   application/javascript, application/ecmascript,
>   application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01",
>   "accommodation_attachments"=>{"image"=>[#,
>   @original_filename="food.png", @content_type="image/png",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"accommodation_attachments[image][]\";
>   filename=\"food.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">]}} Completed
>   400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: what are the params sent on the method POST?

Comment: @Boltz0r I am sorry, but I didn't get what you are asking.

Comment: If you want me to post something, I will do so immediately.

Comment: no my friend... when you put your data in your input form and then submit, even if an error occours you create a method POST with some parameters... its probably in your browser.. something like "id => "1", "blabla" => "blabla"

Comment: Check  `params[:accommodations]`

Comment: @Boltz0r `NetworkError: 400 Bad Request  - http://localhost:3000/accommodations/1/update"`

Comment: Please post the params that get passed through to the controller. You can see these in your log file after "Started POST"

Comment: You've posted your update form, the error is for your create action. Is the create form any different?

Comment: @Matt I have the exact same problem, so`400 Bad Request  - http://localhost:3000/accommodations/create"`

I also updated the post with my POST from development.log

Comment: @Boltz0r I updated the post with my POST from my development.log

Comment: Are your accomodations using Paperclip?  Make sure you specify the "has_attached" method in the accomodation model as specified by the paperclip docs!

Comment: @bkunzi01 I use Carrierwave, but yes, it does have the "has_attached" in it alright. To be precise I have **accommodation_attachments** in each **accommodation**

Comment: you dont have any accomodations_params in your POST method of course its null... i'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See If this works for you

```
def create
    #LINE 12 IS THE NEXT ONE
      @accommodation = Accommodation.new

    if @accommodation.save
        params[:accommodation_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
            @accommodation_attachment = @accommodation.accommodation_attachments.create!(:image => a, :accommodation_id => @accommodation.id)
        end
        @status = 'success'
    else
        @status = 'error'
        @errormessages = @accommodation.errors.full_messages
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

Comment: It does work. But I don't use my **accommodation_params**.
To be honest I don't know if I really need them, but why it didn't work in the first place?

Comment: because you dont have any accomodation_params... your accomodation has an id "automatic" and the attachments... it has no param of his own... so ofcourse accomodations_params was nil

Comment: This is really weird, because the exact same code worked for another model. I mean, I just copy pasted it and and changed the names. Do you believe I need the accommodation_params? I saw it in a carrierwave guide around SO.

Comment: you need the params if you have any params... but accomodations dont have params.... if you had accomodation.name/accomodation.whatever you would need... but you dont! all you have is accomodation.id and accomodation.accomodation_attachments which has a param of their own

Comment: I can't thank you enough for taking the time to explain everything.

Comment: No problem :) glad to help

Comment: The create method works fine, but the update doesn't even though I removed the accommodation_params, I get : `"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error  - http://localhost:3000/accommodations/3/update"`
Would you have some time to discuss it in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113650/discussion-between-boltz0r-and-dyserone).